# Simple Anti-Diamond Pattern in C++ impossible?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have four classes with the following cast (a.k.a. constructor) diagram:

```
    DataBase   ---->  DataDerived

        |                  |
        V                  V

    TableBase  ---->  TableDerived
```

Each table has a data attribute.

## Question

Now, when `obj` is of type `TableDerived` then: How do I make it that `obj.data::DataBase` is being the exact same instance that `obj.TableBase::data` is? (i.e. both accessors are the exact same single one physical reference).

## Implementation

This is my implementation:

```cpp
struct DataBase{
    int i{};
};

struct DataDerived : DataBase{
    int j{};
    DataDerived(DataBase&& d):DataBase(std::move(d)){}
};

// above this line, everything is obvious. Below this line, things are unclear

struct TableBase{
    DataBase data; // may not live on Heap!!
};

struct TableDerived: TableBase{
    DataDerived data;
};
```

## Limitations

I do not want Tables to inherit from Data. I do not want to use dynamic allocation. I need *all* four classes to be whole when stand-alone (no aggregates, only attributes).

## What I tried

The best solution that GPT-4 proposes is with using a shared pointer. That necessitates dynamic allocations, which is undesirable.

I am aware of virtual inheritance. But the way I know it, this would necessitate for Tables to inherit from Data, which appears undesirable to me in terms of what I consider inheritance to mean.

Comment: @MarekR You did not read the remark.

Comment: If you don't want to use the tool C++ gives you to resolve the multiple inheritance, then yes it's impossible to resolve the multiple inheritance.

Comment: don't assume the problem in your code would be obvious. Don't only refer to the solution you dont want. Explain what the issue is. COmpiler errors? Include them in the quesiton. "Very simple stuff. I cannot make it work." why not? Start from there and then we can find a solution.

Comment: Do you need objects of type `TableBase` that are not of type `TableDerived`?

Comment: @Walter Yes, exactly. My real application is something entirely different. Successive specializations of methods that need additional subsets of parameters. These parameter sets are however independent and so are the Methods.

Comment: This all feels very vague. The solution is to those problems is always either a virtual inheritance, CRTP, or in C++23 an explicit this parameter (which is essentially a cleaner replacement for CRTP). E.g. do you need the ability to convert `TableDerived &` to `TableBase &`, or do you just want to avoid retyping the members twice? If you don't need the conversion, do a CRTP between those?

Comment: If I read the question right you want to have just one single inherited instance of `Database` within `TableDerived` – *simplest* to achieve is if both `DataDerived` and `TableBase` inherit *virtually* from `Database` (as mentioned already). So far I don't see any need for the more complex patterns like *CRTP*.

Comment: @Aconcagua the `Table`s aren't inheriting from `Data`s, they have one as a data member

Comment: Yes there is a possible design solution using CRTP to mixin implementations.. But first of all, are you using inheritance to do code reuse or can you really guarantee the Liskov substitution principle? If not look into aggregation, TableBase should use a DataBase. Object oriented doesn't mean everything has to be solved using inheritance.

Comment: This question seems to be based on assumption that inheritance somehow overrides class fields, like it does with overriding `virtual` fuctions. But it does not. Type of each field and layout of object in general is fixed when it is declared so derived object will always have two separate unrelated fields named `data`: `TableDerived::data` and `TableBase::data`. Neither virtual inheritance, nor  CRTP will change it.

Comment: `may not live on Heap` – why, actually? If you permit, you possibly might be able to relinquish inheritance for the table entirely and instead pass the database to its constructor. You might use smart pointers to avoid manual memory management then – which one (unique or shared) depends on the use case, more closely to what you have currently is the unique variant, though you'd need to implement copy constructor manually (if you need one) for duplicating the database. `Database` might provide a virtual `clone` function to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that depending on whether `TableBase` is instantinated on its own or as base of `TableDerived`, the `data` member you want is of different type: in the first case it must be a `DataBase` and in the second `DataDerived`.

However, that is not supported by a static language like C++.

So the simple answer is **No**, this is impossible.

Comment: Okay, so probably I go for an _impl class and use virtual inheritance on that instead. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: A flat out "no" isn't really helpful. Maybe OP doesn't need true inheritance between TableDerived and TableBase, and CRTP is enough. Or something else.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree, but apparently, the real problem is entirely different. They should post their real problem, not their fake problem. What we have here is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: The virtual inheritance is exactly to solve multiple instances of common parent, but he apparently thinks it not what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

(One possible solution out of many) Use private virtual inheritance.

Private inheritance is a variant of containment. It does not model the *is-a* relationship.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

struct DataBase {  };
struct DataDerived : virtual DataBase {  };

struct TableBase : private virtual DataBase {
    virtual DataBase& getData() { return *this; } 
};

struct TableDerived: TableBase,  private virtual DataDerived {
    virtual DataDerived& getData() override { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    TableDerived d;
    DataBase* dbFromDerived = &d.getData();
    std::cout << dbFromDerived << "\n";
    TableBase&  b = d;
    DataBase* dbFromBase = &b.getData();
    std::cout << dbFromBase << "\n";
    assert(dbFromDerived == dbFromBase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an abstract base class, and a class templated on the type of `data`. This slightly changes the syntax to access the data, by adding `()` to those sites.

```
struct TableAbstract{
    virtual DataBase & data() = 0;
};

template <typename Data>
struct Table: TableAbstract {
    DataBase & data() override { return data_; }
    Data & data_derived() { return data_; }
private:
    Data data_;
};
```

To keep the names `TableBase` and `TableDerived` for "table with `DataBase data`" and "table with `DataDerived data`", you can define aliases, but note that `TableBase` isn't a base class of `TableDerived` in this scheme, the base class of both is `TableAbstract`

```
using TableBase = Table<DataBase>;
using TableDerived = Table<DataDerived>;
```